# What are good sites/places to buy/sell bike parts for older bikes?

Tags: maintenance

I've been wondering is there a marketplace to buy/sell/get original parts for bikes no longer made? I have a Bridgestone X0-1 Hybrid (the weird looking one with mustache handlebars) and I want to either restore it to original like new condition (or might just sell it) but I haven't really found a good place to research this. Any ideas?  I've tried ebay, but either its a whole bike (I don't need that) or never the parts I need!

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Changed to community wiki, since there's likely to be multiple equally correct answers

Comment: What is this "sell" thing?  Mine get cleaned and stored in the shed if they're still useful, or recycled if they're worn-out.   Sometimes I give away parts if people have a need and post on the local cycling email lists.

Answer (score 7):

In the UK you can look at [Retrobike](http://www.retrobike.co.uk/).

Comment: Yeah, I am in the states, but still a cool site - thanks!

Comment: Retrobike is cool. There needs to be a US version!

Answer (score 4):

I'd vote for PinkBike or your local Craigslist. I know I look in both spots for parts when I want something new for my bike.

Answer (score 1):

Look for stores that sell used bikes, they'll often have a large selection of parts for sale.

Answer (score 1):

Backpeddling in Guelph Ontario has a great reputation as a source for hard-to-find parts for specific bikes or vintages.  I'd be surprised if you didn't find a great deal of help from these guys: http://www.backpeddling.com/

Answer (score 1):

EBay is your best bet. It actually has a wealth of parts--they just go fast! Set up a saved search for what you are looking for, and it will email you when a match appears!

Answer (score 1):

The UK also has a traditional event called the Bike Jumble. I've never been but I think they specialise in vintage bikes and parts.

http://www.bikejumbles.co.uk/pages/calendar.html

http://www.campyoldy.co.uk/bike-jumble-diary/

At the time of posting this in September 2020, some have been postponed a full year to late 2021 due to covid.